# Expect - send space bar until prompt

Tags: networking, expect

I'm writing an expect script to login to a set of routers and run a command. The problem is different routers have different outputs for the command and so I need to send the space bar until the it displays the whole output.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set f [open "test-ip"]
set ip [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach host $ip {
        set timeout 2
        spawn ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss username@$ip
        sleep 2
        expect "word:"
        send "password\r"
        expect "#"
        send "sh media\r"
        expect {"#" {send "exit\r"}
                "Control-c" { send -- { }; exp_continue}
        }
        expect "#" 
        send "exit\r"
        expect ">"
        send "exit\r"
        close
}
```

Right now it doesn't keep sending the spacebar until it sees a "#".

Edit: Here's the debug

```
--More--, next page: Space, next line: Return key, quit: Control-c" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ""#" {send -- "exit\r"}\n\t\t"Control-c" { send -- " "; exp_continue}\n        "? no
expect: timed out
```

Comment: and ...? I don't see a question in your question.

Comment: It doesn't keep sending " "

Comment: because you're using outer braces, you're actually sending 3 characters (quote, space, quote)

Comment: Are you sure you are matching the "quit: Control-c" prompt? Run with `expect -d` for debugging output.

Comment: Also, because text files end with a newline, then you split on newlines, the last element of the `$ip` list is an empty string. I'd use `set ip [split [read -nonewline $f] \n]`

Comment: I updated the code and now it sends the space once then jumps to the next ssh.

Comment: I got it, I switched the order to `expect { "Control-c" { send -- { }; exp_continue}"#" {send "exit\r"}
                }` and it worked. Your `-d` option helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the order after watching the debug with -d and it's good.

```
    expect {
            "Control-c" { send -- " "; exp_continue}
            "#" {send -- "exit\r"}
    }
```

Comment: Not till tomorrow.